# database upload in android only uploading part of the database

Tags: java, android

I am learning how to create an app for the android, and this app is going to have a database, that is quite large over 600 K records.  I am attempting to get it running with a smaller table, 250K records to test the speed.  Most of the smaller table will load, and so far the app works correctly.  My issue is that only about 33K rows are being uploaded.  I increased the heap size already and it is still doing it.

Anyone know why it is doing this or can point me in the right direction to remedying this?

Comment: How long is it taking to upload the 33k rows?

Comment: Maybe the timeout defaults to a minute?  (Just speculating)

Comment: I did not know there was a timeout.  Any idea how I find out or change it?

Comment: Ah I assumed that you were uploading the DB over a network.  There would be a timeout associated with that.  If you're not, then I am not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: I am populating the db through xml, and it is a local db.

Comment: So just to be clear (for the next person), this is not a network related issue?

Comment: i don't think so, logcat shows that there are no records, then it shows that it has returned the 33k.

Comment: @Jim why don't you want to upload it in batches?

Comment: I didn't think I would have to.  I am learning as i go, and learned from a video at that.  The fact that this works at all is amazing.  What do you suggest?